# How can I force the execution of a PHP file in a global scope?

Tags: php

I have a php file, say include.php which has the following contents:

```
<?php
$myVar = "foo";
?>
```

Now, I want to create a class, called GlobalInclude, which can include a file in the global scope:

```
class GlobalInclude {
    public function include( $file="include.php" ) {
        #do something smart
        include $file
        #do something smart
    }
}
```

In it's current form, the $myVar variable will only be available inside the scope of the include function. I want to do something like:

```
GlobalInclude::include( "include.php" );
echo $myVar;
```

Output
foo

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: My 2 cent: Don't do it. Nobody likes global variables

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to wrap your include inside a class instead of simply in the file in question?

Comment: @KingCrunch. I am working with some old code which is in global scope. I can't afford to make it object oriented.

Comment: @Daniel. Yes. It's kind of difficult to explain the real use case, but I need to call the include inside the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve "require\_global"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751976/how-to-achieve-require-global)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd update the answer here.
I wrapped my app entry in a try catch, and threw a `IncludeInGlobalException` with the file name as the message. Then, in the catch block, I included the file.

Answer (score 0):

Horribly ugly hack:

```
$GLOBALS[$myVar] = $myValue;
```

in the include.php (or whatever file you're actually using).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Sorry, I misread your original post. You can do this by using `get_defined_vars` to grab all variables in the current scope, and return them:

```
public function includeAndGetVars($file) {
  include $file;
  return get_defined_vars();      
}
```

Then after you call your function, use `extract` to dump the results into the current scope:

```
extract(includeAndGetVars("include.php"));
echo $myVar;
```